# What does the Assist camera option do in Only Up 64?

Tags: only-up-64

In the Super Mario 64 romhack [Only Up 64](https://romhacking.com/hack/only-up-64), what does the "Assist" setting in the pause menu camera options do?

[image: Camera options selecting the Assist setting]

Comment: By reading some of the comments, I can infer that Assist Camera will snap the camera to predetermined positions so that you don't have to move it yourself, and many people have preferred to have this option off.

Comment: @Hipposgrumm Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I mean it isn't an 100% sure correct answer since it's an inference but I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading some of the comments, I can infer that Assist Camera will snap the camera to predetermined positions so that you don't have to move it yourself, and many people have preferred to have this option off.